# React Native release build error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'now' of undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm working on a React Native project that was ejected from Expo, and I'm facing an issue specifically when building and running the release version of my app. When I run the app in debug mode using `react-native run-android`, everything works as expected without any errors. However, when I try to create and run the release build using `react-native run-android --mode=release`, I encounter the following error:

```
04-22 07:08:51.606 21291 21354 E AndroidRuntime: TypeError: Cannot read property 'now' of undefined
04-22 07:08:51.606 21291 21354 E AndroidRuntime:     at anonymous (address at index.android.bundle:1:182381)
04-22 07:08:51.606 21291 21354 E AndroidRuntime:     at loadModuleImplementation (address at index.android.bundle:1:36507)
04-22 07:08:51.606 21291 21354 E AndroidRuntime:     at guardedLoadModule (address at index.android.bundle:1:36056)
04-22 07:08:51.606 21291 21354 E AndroidRuntime:     at metroRequire (address at index.android.bundle:1:35684)
04-22 07:08:51.606 21291 21354 E AndroidRuntime:     at anonymous (address at index.android.bundle:1:216106)
04-22 07:08:51.606 21291 21354 E AndroidRuntime:     at loadModuleImplementation (address at index.android.bundle:1:36507)
04-22 07:08:51.606 21291 21354 E AndroidRuntime:     at guardedLoadModule (address at index.android.bundle:1:36056)
04-22 07:08:51.606 21291 21354 E AndroidRuntime:     at metroRequire (address at index.android.bundle:1:35684)
04-22 07:08:51.606 21291 21354 E AndroidRuntime:     at get AppRegistry (address at index.android.bundle:1:52444)
04-22 07:08:51.606 21291 21354 E AndroidRuntime:     at registerRootComponent (address at index.android.bundle:1:1437167)
04-22 07:08:51.606 21291 21354 E AndroidRuntime:     at anonymous (address at index.android.bundle:1:42864)
04-22 07:08:51.606 21291 21354 E AndroidRuntime:     at loadModuleImplementation (address at index.android.bundle:1:36507)
04-22 07:08:51.606 21291 21354 E AndroidRuntime:     at guardedLoadModule (address at index.android.bundle:1:36013)
04-22 07:08:51.606 21291 21354 E AndroidRuntime:     at metroRequire (address at index.android.bundle:1:35684)
04-22 07:08:51.606 21291 21354 E AndroidRuntime:     at global (address at index.android.bundle:1:35268)
04-22 07:08:51.606 21291 21354 E AndroidRuntime:    ... 8 more
```

This error appears to be related to the release build, as the debug build runs without any issues. I'm not sure what's causing this error, and I'm unable to identify the exact location of the problem in my codebase. I have tried cleaning the build and reinstalling the node modules, but the error persists.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or can provide guidance on how to troubleshoot and fix this problem in a React Native release build?

Comment: just to add i have no mention of 'now' im finding in my code

Comment: https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/300

Comment: i tried adding a global date to the index.js still no luck @ChethiyaKD